# Would it be appropriate to delete my question and answer, and then reask the question?

Tags: support, specific-question

Five days ago I have completed my little research on the size of one's vocabulary necessary to read German newspapers. I wanted to share it with the community using the *Stackechange* functionality of "Answer your own question". I had something to say in the answer, but failed to elegantly formulate the question and its body, which has resulted in heavy downvoting and ultimately "on hold" status. Since then I've reformulated the [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31145/how-many-german-words-and-phrases-should-one-know-to-read-and-understand-german/31146#31146). Two individuals have voted to reopen my question (two individuals have also marked my question as their favorite one). However, reopening of a question seems to proceed extremely slow, as opposed to closing one.

So, I'd like to inquire whether deleting my current answer, then deleting my question (to prevent the system from blocking my account for deleting a question which already has an answer), and then re-asking it would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: The [reopen review](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/15086) of your question was completed, but without a positive result. Also note that you have sufficient experience to cast a reopen vote on your question yourself (which would trigger another round of review, if I am not mistaken). I personally consider the question not closeworthy anymore. (As a moderator, I can only reopen the question directly and not cast a regular vote, hence I refrained from doing so to allow the community to decide.)

*The following reflects my personal opinion and is not to be taken as an official moderator decision. Please only apply if this was accepted by the community through voting.*

That being said, even reopening would not do your question much good since it attracted so many downvotes that it will not be visible on the front page. In this extreme case, I consider it acceptable that you delete and re-ask your question. However, be aware that users may still vote to close the new question. Also link to this Meta post to avoid accusations of circumventing the system.

This should **not** be taken as a free pass for reasking **every** closed question and only applies to questions that were substantially edited and heavily downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should not evade closage/downvoting by deleting and reposting. It is done a fair few times over at chemistry and usually leads to an instantaneous mod flag, closure within a few minutes and the mods marking the question as an exact duplicate.

In very specific cases, for example heavy editing that still didn’t lead to reopening and vote reversal, it *may* maybe be acceptable. It is, however, a very thin line and getting on the wrong side would again lead to the above effect. At the very least preemptively explain in a comment why you did that.

Finally, concerning your specific question: [I do not like ‘how many words …’ questions](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22682/15318), I consider them wrong in themselves, not clear enough to be answered and essentially always a duplicate of that one (of which I am still amazed that it stayed open). ‘How many words …’ is, in my opinion, always the wrong thing to ask. As such, I would close vote your reposted question equally quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example question, it might IMHO have made (a lot of) sense if you had included a hint that you intend to self-answer this.

You apparently did a lot of research for that answer and some of the downvotes for the question might have been related to the potential effort involved in properly answering your question along the line of "does he really expect we invest that amount of work for answering?"

Comment: My main issue was and still is that the answer fails to take the varying frequency of words into account. I have therefore again downvoted it.